# ion-nav-back-button not firing state controller

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

So, I am using ui-router for my app's routing. There is a scenario, I clicked like button on the item detail page. Then I hit back button, it goes back to the main page, it is a list of items. The item has a likes counter. But I found the counter did not increase because back button did not fire the controller for main page. 
I want to understand how can I fire the controller while clicking back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should isolate your data in a provider to manage the data sync between your views. If all of the data is contained in a service, you can update it from one view, and it will always be synced with the other.

In both of the controllers, require 'ItemRepository' which will provide the data to the views.

Comment: Yes, this approach works. How come I did not come up with.. Thanks!